# Separate user data from other data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Our client would like the user table to be separated from all other tables for "security reasons". Is this a good practice given that our application is built using RoR and MySQL and running on Unicorn and Nginx ?

I can think of two possible ways:

- Create two different login accounts, one for the user table and one for the other tables.

OR

- Have a separate database for the user data.

I think that both the solutions might create some problems with the migrations and other tasks and I don't know if this is an effective method of protecting user data. I am a junior developer and I am not familiar with some database and security concepts. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hire someone here for 5 hours. Your candidates might be among those that answer below

Comment: I am a junior and I can't hire anyone, I am the one who is supposed to do it! :(

Comment: Give more info on what you mean by user data and how many apps with legitimate different databases. On premise or cloud. Put all that in question above with Edit link under it

Answer (score 0):

A very common pattern is to have the users table literally just contain details of the user account and NO details of the actual person behind that account.  ie, it would have username, email, password, or encrypted password & salt or whatever, but nothing else - not even name.  So, all the "glue" that makes the system work stays in the users table in your regular database.

Then, the details of the real person behind the account (name, telephone number, address, card details etc etc) are stored in a different table, or tables, with a foreign key in either table pointing into the other one. You could store them in a different database but i don't know if this makes it more secure.  A better way might be to encrypt just the table with the user's personal data, or perhaps encrypt the entire database. see

http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/

I get the feeling that your client doesn't know a lot about internet security and just needs to be reassured that some hacker isn't going to put all the customers' credit card details online, as has happened in several high profile cases recently.  To satisfy them i would recommend that you research this well and implement at least two different security strategies, each of which on their own would be considered adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Reassuring the client didn't work as this was an acceptance criteria for launch. In the end, I created two separate database with separate login credentials and user permissions. In order to manage multiple database migrations, I initially used multi-database-migrations [gem](https://github.com/azitabh/multi-database-migrations) and then customised it into my own [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/multi-database-9000).
I was new to SO when I posted this question (still am) and I now understand that the topic is too wide to be asked in a single SO question. Thanks for the suggestions anyway and I hope that the answer can help other people.